# Parse Json object which contains complex data

Tags: json, spring, jakarta-ee, jackson

Cannot parse json string which containing two simple fields and one object. I use jackson library.I Always get 400 error

JSON:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "categories": "{"name":"Sport","id":1}",
    "name": "sdsd"
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCategory(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Polls polls) {


        pollsService.add(polls);

        URI uri = new UriTemplate("{requestUrl}/{username}").expand(request.getRequestURL().toString(), polls.getId());
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.put("Location", Collections.singletonList(uri.toASCIIString()));
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> containing two simple fields and one object.

That's not what you posted in the example code.  The example code that is likely meant to represent JSON is actually not valid JSON.  It contains two string elements, and something that is not JSON.

Following is a valid JSON example similar to what was originally posted.

```
{
    "id": "",
    "categories": {"name":"Sport","id":1},
    "name": "sdsd"
}
```